Webpack v5 - Can't disable chunks
I have multiple entry points in my webpack config and I want each entry point to bundle into its own folder with nothing
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';

// Entry files
const entries = {
  entry1: './src/entry/entry1.ts',
  entry2: './src/entry/entry2.ts',
  entry3: './src/entry/entry3.ts',
};

export default {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: entries,
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: '[name]/index.js',
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    clean: true, 
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: false,
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          format: {
            comments: false,
          }
        },
        extractComments: false,
      })
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    extensionAlias: {
        '.js': ['.ts', '.js'],
        '.mjs': ['.mts', '.mjs'],
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            configFile: path.resolve('tsconfig.json'),
          },
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    }),
  ],
};

I can't get it to not generate a folder with a chunk in addition to the entry folders. I want all the code to sit inside the entry files so they are standalone, how can I disable these chunks, I've tried a lot of different options with split chunks

Found the answer on github, to disable chunking pass chunkFormat:
Use the output section of the config, not the optimization section:

{
  output: {
    chunkFormat: false
  }
}

